# Where is the line of code that adds angular to the window object?

Tags: angularjs, global

I know angular gets added to window, but [looking through the library](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js), I can't find where!

Angular is enclosed in an IIFE, so where in the code does it actually get added to window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being initialized below the method call `setupModuleLoader` by calling `ensure` method:

```
function ensure(obj, name, factory) {
    return obj[name] || (obj[name] = factory());
}

var angular = ensure(window, 'angular', Object);
```

This code is first checking if there is an object with name `angular` available in window object and if not then create a new instance of `Object` and assigning it to `angular` variable.

**Update**:

In Javascript if we want to create a new instance, we can create a new instance of any function in three different ways:

```
function A() {
      // some code
}

var a1 = new A();
var a2 = new A;
var a3 = A();
```

So, we are passing `Object` class and accepting in `factory` variable and by calling `factory()` we are creating new object instance which will be assigned into `angular` variable.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. I see this is inside setupModuleLoader(window) which in turn is called inside publishExternalAPI, which is called at the very end of the file. So I guess what angular is doing is waiting until everything is fully initialized before it publishes itself to a property on window. Anything else interesting I should know about all this?

Comment: One more question...where is the function factory()?

Comment: It looks like it's calling Object(). What's going on there?

Answer (score 0):

Mainly these few line of code assign window to $window. this code is taken from angular library:

```
$provide.provider({
        $window: $WindowProvider,
      });  

function valueFn(value) {return function() {return value;};}

function $WindowProvider() {
  this.$get = valueFn(window);
}
```